# ASP.NET Core Web API and roles authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization

I write an application where ASP.NET Core Identity is responsible for authentication and authorization on the server. I also use JWT tokens in this purpose. Everything works fine, besides authorization based on roles. Simple [Authorize] attribute works, I need to be logged in to get the resource, but when I use [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")] none gets authorization.

```
private static async Task CreateUsers(
     RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
     UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
       {
           string role_Administrator = "Administrator";
           string role_RegisteredUser = "RegisteredUser";

           await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role_Administrator));
           await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role_RegisteredUser));

           var user_Admin = new ApplicationUser()
           {
               SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
               UserName = "Admin",
               Email = "admin@test.com",
           };

           await userManager.CreateAsync(user_Admin, "Pass4Admin");
           await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin, role_RegisteredUser);
           await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin, role_Administrator);
}
```

And example method from controller

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

I thought Identity is able to check roles assigned to authenticated user basing on data from created tables like aspnetroles and aspnetuserroles when the request comes from a client application, but apparently I don't understand something about this mechanism and I should configure it somehow.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AppUsers");
        }
    }
```

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddEntityFrameworkMySql();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
             options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
            })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
            {
                opts.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Key"])),
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Audience"],
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,

                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
                cfg.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
                     policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
            });

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(WebMappingProfile));

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
                {
                    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
                });

        }

      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var roleManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                dbContext.Database.Migrate();
                DbSeeder.Seed(dbContext, roleManager, userManager);
            }

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); 
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Did you set config authorization in webconfig?

Comment: share your `DbConctext`

Comment: show your `Startup.cs` and why you want to use `appusers` rather than the default `AspNetUsers` and do you correctly setting FK with `AspNetUserRoles` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add role into your token as claim if you use custom jwt middleware

login action and token generator :

```
var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();



var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                    new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType,role.FirstOrDefault())
                }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(_applicationSettings.Token_Expire_Day),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_applicationSettings.JWT_Secret)),
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
```

Comment: Thanks, only this solution eventually worked. But this is necessary to modify the token? Or it's just workaround?

Comment: You could define an IAuthorizationRequirement and use dependency injection to give the requirement code access to your roles database to resolve this. However it is customary to resolve this at login and put the roles in the token as claims because that way you only have code for resolving roles in one place which keeps it coherent as your app security evolves.